# discord.py bot finds channel messages to delete, but is showing its client id is the same as mine

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command called '!clear' that just removes the bots messages in a specific channel. This seems pretty straight forward using:

```
Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!clear"):
        async for x in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit = 100):
            if str(message.author.id) == 'insert bots client id':
                await client.delete_message(x)
client.run(token)
```

However, i found it wasn't deleting any messages. So before checking message.author.id i added a simple print(message.author.id) to see what ids it is picking up. It appears that it is spitting out only my client id and not seeing its own messages. The weird thing though is that if i change the author.id check to my client id then it will delete my messages and also the bots messages. So for some reason the bot thinks that its client id is the same as mine so when it is in a server that isn't my test server, it doesn't have the right permissions to delete my messages so it fails, even though I only want it to delete its own messages.

Any help would be great.

Comment: In your test setup, the bot is probably posting as you. However, is the bot able to post messages in the non-test setup with your client id, and unable to delete those same messages?

Comment: If i right click the bot in discord and 'copy id', it is very different than mine, even in my test channel. Yet will still delete its own messages if i tell it to delete only messages with my client id.

Regarding another server, it appears to be posting with its own id, but fails due to permissions when it tries to delete mine, which is always first due to the '!clear' message.

Comment: My guess is that your test channel is configured incorrectly, or your bot is not using the test channel properly. My question was, "Shouldn't it work in not-test, with the bot's own id?" If it's using its own ID, it should not get permission denied for deleting its own posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mean

```
if x.author.id == "bot id here":
    await client.delete_message(x)
```

After all, each message is being put in `x` each iteration. Using `message` refers to the message in the `async def on_message(message)` function. Which would be the person who used the command. aka, you.

Comment: wow, cant believe i didn't catch that. Thank you! That fixed it.